# What could be causing two different laptops both with Wireless-N adapters to have very different speeds?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter, internet-speed

My dad recently bought a Dell XPS 14 laptop that had an integrated Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235 wireless adapter, but it appears to be known to drop connections a lot. He'll suddenly get disconnecte from his office WiFi and not being able to reconnect without restarting or diagnosing the adapter, which is annoying.

I recently got him a NetGear WNA3100M adapter, which is supposed to be top of the line 300 Mbps N, but he just called me today about it not reaching any decent speeds.

His office has a 100 Mbps connection that he's been able to test with SpeedTest.net. He usually gets 65 Mbps on the test, so when he saw he was getting 7 Mbps with the new adapter, he was not happy about it.

His old Dell laptop that has a Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN adapter and that is still reaching ~65 Mbps.

To confirm if it was the new adapter, I disabled the NetGear adapter and enabled the Intel one, and he got ~12 Mbps, which is still way less than the 65 Mbps he's currently seeing on his old laptop.

I've checked every configuration and settings I can think of to see if there was a misconfiguration anywhere, but I couldn't find anything. Both laptops (old and new) are not running anything else at the time, they use the same DNS servers, they are both set to A/G/N, I set the channel to 20Mhz on the new one as it was on the old one.

The old laptop uses Windows 7, while the new one uses Windows 8.

I am sorry I don't have the ipconfig /all output right now, but I detailed everything I remembered. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks!